# EXCEL process remain after closing the UI

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in

I have an Excel VSTO add-in that once it has been loaded will prevent the Excel process from closing when closing the window.

I have created a special logging build to try and see what the issue is. According to the logs all of the shut down logic in the add-in is working as expected.

Looking at the memory dump of the Excel process shows that the main thread is locked inside one of the office DLLS.

Does anyone know what the mso20win32client.dll is does? Maybe if I knew what that DLL does I would know what portion of my add-in's code is triggering this issue.

Has anyone had any similar issues with the Excel process not closing and being stuck in mso20win32client.dll?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I created this question at the request of Microsoft support. The code in question is proprietary and cannot be shared. There is also a significant amount of code as well.

That is why I would like to know what the mso20win32client.dll does. Maybe if I understood what that DLL does I might be able to track down what piece of my code is getting stuck in there.